# Java Spring - Request rejected because no multipart boundary was found, when trying to upload PDF file

Tags: java, spring, http, pdf

**PLEASE READ THE EDIT BELOW**

I am trying to create a file archive program that receives a POST request with a pdf file in it's requestBody embedded and then save that pdf file directly into a Database.
But I receive a "unsupported Media Type" and "Content type 'application/pdf;charset=UTF-8' not supported" error message on Postman, as well as this in Eclipse when sending the request:

```
2020-05-25 11:20:58.551  WARN 3944 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/pdf;charset=UTF-8' not supported]
```

below is my current code. I've looked up multiple similar questions on here, but to no avail. 
I am using Postman to send out my POST requests. 
Here is the code of my Controller Class.

```
private final DocumentRepository docRepository;
private final DocumentService documentService;



/*@Autowired
public Controller(DocumentRepository docRepository, FileStorage fileStorage, DocumentService documentService) {
    this.docRepository = docRepository;
    this.fileStorage = fileStorage;
    this.doc
}*/

// Just for testing purposes
@GetMapping("/files")
public List<Document> files() {
    return docRepository.findAll();
}


// POST Method. Add a new entry to the Database. 
// WIP. Works, but creates 2 new columns "file_name" and "size_in_bytes" with the values
// instead of inserting them under the actual made "fileName" and "sizeInBytes" columns

@PostMapping(value="/document", consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public Optional<Document> postDocument(@RequestHeader(value="fileName") String fileName, @RequestBody MultipartHttpServletRequest file
        ) {

    Optional<Document> result = documentService.postToDB(fileName, file);


    return result;
}
```

}

And then the code for the Service Class that handles the logic.
@Service
public class DocumentService {

```
public static String directory = System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/test_uploads";

private final DocumentRepository docRepository;


public DocumentService(DocumentRepository docRepository) {
    this.docRepository = docRepository;

}

public Optional<Document> postToDB(String fileName, MultipartHttpServletRequest file) {

    // temporary counter to see if there already is another entry with the same name
            // temporary id to compare all the ids and iterate the one with the biggest value.
            int counter=0;
            int temp_id=0;
            Timestamp current_timestamp = new Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());


            // This loop is supposed to look if there already is an entry with the same file name, if yes, then the counter will get iterated by 1.
            // Bugged. It will still add a new entry that has a identical file name with another entry as of right now.
            for(int i = 0; i < docRepository.count(); i++) {
                if(docRepository.findAll().get(i).getFileName() == fileName) {
                    counter = counter + 1;

                }
            }

            // This checks if the counter is less than one, thus asking if there are 1 or more file name duplicates
            if (counter < 1) {

                // This gets every ID of every entry and saves them on the temporary variable
                for(int i = 0; i < docRepository.count(); i++) {
                    temp_id= docRepository.findAll().get(i).getId();

                // It is then checked if the next entry is bigger than the previously saved value, if yes, then the variable gets overwritten
                // with the bigger ID until the biggest ID stands.
                        if(docRepository.findAll().get(i).getId() > temp_id) {
                            temp_id = docRepository.findAll().get(i).getId();
                        }

                }

                // after the for-loop closes, the new File will get added with the biggest ID +1 and the fileName in the Header of the POST request.
                Optional<Document> service_result;
                try {
                    service_result = DataAccess.saveEntry(fileName,file, temp_id, docRepository, current_timestamp, 1 );

                    return service_result;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            } 

            else {
                return Optional.empty();
            }

}
}
```

and then finally, the DataAcces Class that saves the requests.

```
public class DataAccess {

public static Optional<Document> saveEntry(String fileName, MultipartHttpServletRequest file, Integer temp_id, DocumentRepository docRepository, Timestamp updated, Integer version) throws IOException {

    docRepository.save(new Document(temp_id +1,fileName+ ".pdf",file.getFile(fileName).getBytes(), file.getFile(fileName).getSize(),updated, version));
        return docRepository.findById(temp_id +1);
}
```

}

**EDIT 1**: I changed consumes to form-data and I send the POST request in Postman with a custom content-type header with application/form-data.

```
@PostMapping(value="/document", consumes="multipart/form-data")
public Optional<Document> postDocument(@RequestHeader(value="fileName") String fileName, @RequestBody MultipartHttpServletRequest file
        ) {

    Optional<Document> result = documentService.postToDB(fileName, file);


    return result;
}
```

Now it seems to work, but I now get a new exception:
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found